# Debug and Trace logs from Azure Function (.net Core 3.1) not visible in Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure-functions, trace, ilogger

I'm trying to get the Debug and Trace logs to Application Insights via ILogger, but unfortunately it's not going my way.

I've made the simplest of demos and I get the INFO, WARN, & ERR logs to Application Insights - but not anything lower than INFO.

I've found several posts here on the same topic, but none that seems to solve my issue.

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks

**From AI Transaction Search**

[image]

**demo function**

```
public static class AIDemoConfig
{
    [FunctionName("AIDemo")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {   
        log.LogTrace("TRACE: C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        log.LogDebug("DEBUG: C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        log.LogInformation("INFO: C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        log.LogWarning("WARN: C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        log.LogError("ERROR: C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string responseMessage = "Hello Log World";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup() { }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        //Add ApplicationInsights
        string applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey))
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddApplicationInsights(applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey);
                builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(typeof(AIDemoConfig).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);
                builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Error);
            });

            builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        }

        builder.Services.AddMvcCore();
        builder.Services.AddOptions();
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Values": {
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "4e0bfb46-68a4-4622-942a-0f80920a82a9"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you also need to check the `host.json` file as [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) introduced how to set log level like below:

> For logs of Host.Results or Function, only log events at Error or a
> higher level.

```
{
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Error",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that did the tick! :) 

Now get all the logs to AI - however, a side effect seems to be that the function console logging stopped (only get "Executing AIDemo..." and "Executed AIDemo...").

Also, restricting the log level for a specific function does not work, e.g. "Function.AIDemo": "Information", - but that's' another issue ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, I'm glad to see it worked for you : )